# Italy: How to withdraw INPS contributions?

Tags: united-kingdom, italy, social-security, pension

I have made two years worth of INPS contributions to the Italian Pension system. My wife who made similar contributions in Austria, was able to withdraw her entire amount minus some fees.

I already got a document from the INPS portal listing all of my contributions.

However, is there a way for me to withdraw those contributions to UK (where I am a resident now)? or wholly withdraw those contributions to my account?

Comment: hello @katman I have the same question...are you available for consulting or know of someone who is?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to receive Italian pension payments from abroad in general, but the eligibility rules are so complicated that it's impossible to answer definitively in your particular case without more data--at minimum your age, the year your first contribution was made, and whether you hold EU citizenship.

Settled EU/EEA citizens with only 2 years would normally have their contributions counted toward [qualifying for a UK pension](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/benefits-and-pensions-for-eea-and-swiss-citizens-in-the-uk) because they won't meet the [minimum distribution rules for Italy with that amount](https://www.inps.it/prestazioni-servizi/la-domanda-di-pensione-in-regime-comunitario-dipendenti-privati).